# Ansible, load /etc/profile from playbook

Tags: bash, ansible, vagrant, virtualbox

Please I have a problem when I try to reload bash profile located in /etc/profile.

I tried to load it in many ways, from
command: `.  /etc/profile` and with script file with script module and shell as well.

Ansible give my changed status for all, but when I tried to echo the variables inside the profile eg `echo $myname` they print nothing after finishing execution in playbook.

when I tried to load it again with terminal `. /etc/profile` the variables is loaded and I can echo it's value.

also I make a script file inside the profile.d directory and load it with Ansible nothing happens.

> ps. full root permissions is given with become and `--ask-become-pass`
>   parameter.  I'm using vagrant box with centos 7 X64.

Thank you...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ansible load my Variables into my global profile, it's ok not changed as it's already placed in that profile

[image]

I pass the script in same environment, so the java read the variables successfully
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Sourcing the profile will only be good for a single task.

For example, if your *personal* profile (I'm not getting to `/etc/profile` yet) sets `myname=Ameen`, then in the following code, the first task should echo your name, but the second should not:

```
- shell: 'cd; . ./.bash_profile; echo "[$myname]"`
- shell: 'echo "[$myname]"'
```

Every task is a distinct environment. Variables set in a local shell environment will not be available for another environment that connects later but does not set them again for itself.

My output:

```
[Ameen]
[]
```

2. bash uses `.bash_profile`, which typically sources `~/.bashrc`, which usually sources `/etc/bashrc`.

In `ksh` it's usually `~/.profile`, `~/.kshrc`, and `/etc/profile`, though all of these are obviously configurable, just convention that can be totally done differently on a given system, though you should consider why.

3. Are you really expecting `myname` to be set in the global profile all users source?

Or is that just an example for your question?

Comment: Hey Paul,
Thank you very much, it's worked.
myname is just an example, if you want what I do, please check my answer below.